# depth first search with 2D Array

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures, stack

I have an array like that :

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And I want to group elements which are '1'.

So you see I have a classical dfs by using a stack. The question is, If I have a matrix like the above, what is the time complexity of this algorithm where `n` is the number of matrix elements. (Row*column).If it worse than `O(N)` (since I must traverse whole 2D array) which approach will help me to improve this algorithm?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what N is. The answer is probably O(…)

Comment: You will find the answer by counting the number of times every pixel is visited.

Answer (score 1):

### Example of an O(n * log n) algorithm

(where *n* is the number of matrix elements)

The idea of the algorithm is as follows.

1. Initialize a treeset of unhandled elements *U* by adding all matrix elements into it
2. While *U* isn't yet empty, take any *u* from *U* and check it for its value

   - If *u* = '0' then just remove it, i.e. *U* := *U \ {u}*
   - If *u* = '1' then start exploration *DFS(u, U)*

Where procedure *DFS(u, U)* uses the matrix to explore the '1' neighbours of *u*.

However, here comes the kicker, *DFS(u, U)* also removes every discovered element from *U*.

It is rather easy to understand and prove that this algorithm indeed always finishes in O(n * log n). Deleting an element from a treeset has worst-case complexity O(log n). Each *DFS(u, U)* run can visit at most *|U|* elements, and each element visited through any means is removed from *U* as the execution progresses. The algorithm terminates when *U* becomes empty.

### Short summary

It is possible to produce an *O(n^2)* algorithm for example by running DFS on each element regardless of your previously attained knowledge.
Using any mechanism ensuring that you don't run DFS on an already discovered group/island is likely to produce a superior algorithm.

*Sorry that I can't analyze your own algorithm directly, but this may help you do it on your own.*

Comment: Okay, another way. I will push just '1' s to a list. then iterate over the list by a single loop, for every item check DFS with using stack. There is no problem until the deleting. DFS deletes all neighbours, retains just first occurence right ?(So i can count number of different islands) When removing a element from the list which you described U the complexity for removing is O(N) ? or not ?. So it comes O(N'2) again. Am i wrong ?

Comment: Adding only '1's sounds like a suitable upgrade, yes. DFS however should delete every '1' discovered, including the one where it started. It really is important to empty list U so that you know when to terminate. In order to remember your discovered islands, each DFS run can store this info in some other variable, but probably not in list U.

Comment: You have a great point that removing a particular element from a list can have complexity O(n). However, you can use some more suitable data structure based on search trees or hash tables (Java Sets or Maps), which can do it in O(log n) or even O(1). For a HashMap, O(1) is not the worst case complexity. I suppose in a purely apocalyptic worst-case scenario, this would make the complexity actually O(n * log n). Great Catch. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound of the algorithm that you need to devise should be `O(m+n)` - I am considering the number of rows and columns as `m` and `n` respectively. This is because you need to traverse the whole 2D array anyway. If you are solving this using two for loops, this will take `O(m+n)` as well. For each element in your matrix, you will compare with other 4 adjacent elements and hence, the overall checking size is `<= 4mn`.

I think there is no better way to solve this in less than `O(m+n)` time.

Please note that in your question, if you are considering `m+n = N` then the complexity that I am referring to is `O(N)`.

Comment: Yes, I mean r*c = n which is the number of elements. What is the correct approach to count number of islands by using stack.

Comment: Oh... I see. You do have a requirement of solving it using a stack. Now I understand. I was just generalizing the problem and the solution. Let me think about it and will get back to you if I find anything interesting. Thanks. :)

Comment: yes, everything i tried was stucked with O(n^2). Thanks.

Comment: I think, with 2 nested for loop, there is (r*c) which is n. And then inside this nested loops, searching with stacks gives n. So total is n^2. Am i right?